# Why is VS Code running python files but in certain window highlighting syntax only half-way and not linting

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a couple of days now my vs code (on mac) stopped linting and half-way syntax highlighting python files. I usually work with 3 windows and the weird thing is that it is happing only inside one of them. The code runs by the way. But no auto-completion, variables are grey etc..
I changed the python env, I disabled diverse extension, but it doesn't help.
Sometimes I observe vs code analysing 1 file - feels like it does it forever..

What could be the problem?

Here's a screenshot of the imported modules - they should be green

[image]

Here's a screenshot of some code:

[image]

Comment: what do you see if you use VSC Insiders with the Microsoft Python and PyLance extensions, no additional extensions, no additional themes

Comment: With the Insiders version and only python extension installed the code appears as it should. Except that is shows errors which are not errors in regular vs code

Comment: are you using Python 2.x? What errors do you get?

Comment: "...possibly unbound" errors, but I got rid of them. I use Python 3.x